# Java (Processing) object serialization

Tags: java, serialization, stream, processing

I'm trying to make a 3D matrix of coloured squares with processing. It works fine but when I want to save it to a file serializing the DataMatrix Object I get this exception: java.io.NotSerializableException. Both Square and DataMatrix implement Serializable so I don't know what might be causing it.

FileManager:

```
class FileManager
{

  FileManager()
  {}

  public void saveMatrix(String path, DataMatrix dm)
  {
    try
    {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(path);
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    output.writeObject(dm); 
    output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 

  public DataMatrix openMatrix(String path)
  {
    DataMatrix dm = null;

    try
    {

       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
       ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(file);
       Object aux = input.readObject();
       input.close();
       if(aux instanceof DataMatrix)
       {
         dm = (DataMatrix)aux;
       }        
    }
    catch (EOFException e1)
    {
       System.out.println ("Fin de fichero");
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dm; 
  }
}
```

Data Matrix:

```
class DataMatrix implements Serializable
{

  Square[][][] dataMatrix;

  DataMatrix()
  { 
      dataMatrix = new Square[5][32][32];
  }

  public void setSquare(int x, int y, int z, color c, String type)
  {

     dataMatrix[z][x][y].setSquare(c,type);   

  }
```

Square:

```
class Square implements Serializable
{

  public int x;
  public int y;
  public int z;
  public color c;
  public String type;

  Square(int xx, int yy, int zz, color cc, String tt){
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    z = zz;
    c = cc;
    type = tt; 
  }

  public void setSquare(color cc, String tt){

    c = cc;
    type = tt;

  }

  public void printSquare()
  {
     println(green(c) +"  "+ type); 
  }

}
```

Error log:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: processing.core.PApplet$InternalEventQueue
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at maindatamatrix$FileManager.saveMatrix(maindatamatrix.java:105)
    at maindatamatrix.setup(maindatamatrix.java:30)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2245)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:243)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: processing.core.PApplet$InternalEventQueue
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at maindatamatrix$FileManager.openMatrix(maindatamatrix.java:123)
    at maindatamatrix.setup(maindatamatrix.java:33)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2245)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:243)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: processing.core.PApplet$InternalEventQueue
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at maindatamatrix$FileManager.saveMatrix(maindatamatrix.java:105)
    at maindatamatrix.setup(maindatamatrix.java:30)
    ... 4 more
```

I tought it might be the color class so I used the transient modifier to check it. Still the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: What is that `color` ?

Comment: It's a native class in Processing

Comment: @Phob1a what do you mean with "native class"?

Comment: You don't actually implement any of the methods from the Serializable interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Sorry I don't know if "native" was the correct term. What I mean is that it comes with Processing, you don't need to import anything.

Comment: `color` is just an `int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this I had to:

- rename all classes which implement Serializable to **.java**, so **DataMatrix** becomes **DataMatrix.java** and **Square** becomes **Square.java**
- use `int` instead of `color` in these classes
- add missing imports in these classes

Here is the code:

SerializableTest.pde:

```
void setup(){
  DataMatrix dm = new DataMatrix();
  FileManager f = new FileManager();
  f.saveMatrix("/Users/me/test", dm);
}
```

DataMatrix.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class DataMatrix implements Serializable
{

  Square[][][] dataMatrix;

  DataMatrix()
  { 
      dataMatrix = new Square[5][32][32];
  }

  public void setSquare(int x, int y, int z, int c, String type)
  {

     dataMatrix[z][x][y].setSquare(c,type);   

  }
}
```

FileManager.pde:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;

class FileManager
{

  FileManager()
  {}

  public void saveMatrix(String path, DataMatrix dm)
  {
    try
    {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(path);
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    output.writeObject(dm); 
    output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 

  public DataMatrix openMatrix(String path)
  {
    DataMatrix dm = null;

    try
    {

       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
       ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(file);
       Object aux = input.readObject();
       input.close();
       if(aux instanceof DataMatrix)
       {
         dm = (DataMatrix)aux;
       }        
    }
    catch (EOFException e1)
    {
       System.out.println ("Fin de fichero");
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dm; 
  }
}
```

Square.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import processing.core.*;

class Square implements Serializable
{

  public int x;
  public int y;
  public int z;
  public int c;
  public String type;

  Square(int xx, int yy, int zz, int cc, String tt){
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    z = zz;
    c = cc;
    type = tt; 
  }

  public void setSquare(int cc, String tt){

    c = cc;
    type = tt;

  }

  public void printSquare()
  {
     //System.out.println(PApplet.green(c) +"  "+ type);
    int g = (c >> 8) & 0xFF;   // Faster way of getting green(argb)
    System.out.println(g); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

its seems that in File manager class ,inside try block The fields of your object have in turn their fields, some of which do not implement Serializable...

if color class implements serializable..??
if you are using some 3rd party library  which are not serializable try xml based serialization or others serialization forms like json..

Comment: There is no class **color**. The Processing IDE treats color variables as **ints**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I actually tested your code, but changed the unknown color class for a simple String. It wrote the file without complains, so, I would assume the following:

1. Maybe when you declared transient, you still ran the older compiled version? This can happen depending on how you setup your compiling/runtime environment.
2. The color class could be causing issues then. Can you exactly provide the package name of that class so we can look for it?
3. In your imports, are you 100% sure that you're importing like this? It has happened to me, mostly in eclipse, that you grab a wrong import when you let Eclipse help you out.

   import java.io.Serializable;
4. What version of Java are you using and where are you running your code? It looks like part of an Applet?

According to your last answer, I could recommend the following:

Store 3 variables in your Square class:

```
private int r;
private int g;
private int b;

public void setColor(int r, int g, int b) {
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
}

public color getColor() {
    return color(r, g, b);
}
```

This way you get rid of the color serialization issue.

By the way, I'm assuming you mean this by Processing: http://processing.org

Answer (score 1):

Oracle itself has deemphasized the Serializable interface and the DataInputStream and the DataOutputStream classes.

The trouble with this old-fashioned kind of serialization is that if you change fields in your object that need to be saved into your binary file, then your existing files are incompatible with your newer versions of your software.

I suggest that you define your own file formats and stay in charge of your own destiny.  It takes a little effort up front, but then you don't "paint yourself into a corner" long term.

I would rather use an XML file than Java's old-fashioned serialization.

Or if you really want a binary file, you can use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream and read and write your own fields.

But I think that XML is best because the resulting files are "human readable" and even "human editable".

When I design a file format (or a format for data to be transmitted) I think that it's a good idea to have a version number which identifies which version of the file format that it is.  You may not need this file-format version number, but having it just gives you more flexibility in the future.